# Prototype Tooltip - controlling "orientation"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype, tooltip, viewport

As you can see in this screenshot, the way the tooltip displays it is cut off by the viewport.  If I can force the tooltip to display upwards, as opposed to downwards, then it wouldn't but cut off.

Any ideas on how I can display this in a more user-friendly way?

[image]

Comment: How are you generating the tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [prototip](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/) then you can hook it to your mouse and it will stay in the viewport. Also, (and I haven't tried this but the docs seem to indicate it), setting viewport=true without hooking will keep it in the viewport as well.